# Java Servlet not writing large response

Tags: servlets, jboss7.x

I have a simple servlet which is running on JBoss 7.1. I am facing this problem that when the response is very large, the servlet truncates it which causes problem at the destination. How can I solve this problem. Following is the response code from my servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
{
  PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
  response.setContentType("text/xml");
  response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  writer.write(the desired response);
  writer.flush();
  writer.close();

}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in this piece of code.  How have you tested it?  Maybe the problem is on the client side.

Comment: There is no problem on the client in case of a small response, therefore, there must a be problem with response size, timeout etc

Comment: More info needed. How large is the file, and why are you writing out a huge file with `writer.write()`?

Comment: It's possible the client is only seeing a partial response because the buffer size is hit and it's being flushed to the client. Have a look a the `HttpServletResponse.setBufferSize()`.